# Ssl System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException:

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ssl, iis-7, asmx

I have a web service and it is working properly when i test is but when i try to use it inside of a client application with a self created ssl certificate i am getting this error

The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException
```

I have read so many documents and made some research effort but nothing can solve the problem yet. I would be appriciated if any one helps

Comment: have you added the self signed cert to your trusted certificate store?

Comment: Yes i did. I think it is about non-matching of ssl cert name and host name but i don't know how can i make them matched.

Comment: Do you have the full error? When I used selfed signed certificates (for SSL Streams) I used a callback to manually validate the certificate in code against the hash of the authentic certificate. I believe this is what you need to do in order to get around the error as well as avoid MiTM attacks.

Comment: Yes i think so, but i dont know where to put these codes and i dont' have these validation codes correctly. I have these         
`System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);`

Comment: You probably want to give the validation callback an actual function.

Comment: @Mausimo i don't get what you try to mean ?

Comment: This seems wrong: System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);  I will have to look it up, but I am in the middle of something.

Comment: @Mausimo Do you know where to put this validation codes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your SSL certificate is self-signed, you must custom validate the certificate. Even if you have added this certificate to your Trusted Ceritifcate Store, you still need to do this.

This is just off the top of my head, but I think it should be something like this:

```
ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);

private bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
//Use sslPolicyErrors to check what the error is for the certificate.

//Validate your certificate.
//Check Hash for MiTM attack.

//Decide if it is good, then return true, else return false.
return true;
}
```